# 'Track the next one' button is hard to read for privileges on GIS SE?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

Whenever you reach a certain reputation level corresponding to a new privilege, the system will tell you about it on your profile page:

[image]

The 'Track the next one' button is hard to read because it's in orange/brown; I've checked a handful of other sites in the network and it looks much better in white:

[image]

Comment: I'm following the advice [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240571/295232): *For bugs that affect only a particular site (for example, a CSS bug in one of the themed sites, or a bug that is data-dependent), please ask on the meta for that site.* Bugs on child metas are also seen by SE developers.

Comment: Is this still a problem with the [new updated theme of GIS that went into testing today](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4941/giss-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing?cb=1)?  As a 30K+ user I am unable to test this particular aspect.

Comment: That's where socks are for :P But you're right, it seems to be [status-completed]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAKWT.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [your comment](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/track-the-next-one-button-is-hard-to-read-for-privileges-on-gis-se?noredirect=1#comment9412_4930) this seems to be non-reproducible using the new updated theme of GIS ([GIS's updated site theme is ready for testing!](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4941)) so I'll mark this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

[image]