# Change title font to prevent confusion between the number zero and letter o (0o)

Tags: feature-request, title

**Numbers display strangely in the font used for titles in the new site theme.**

Numbers 3, 4, 5, 7 and 9 hang below the string horizontal gravity center. Examples [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A3).

Numbers 0, 1 and 2 are shrunken. Examples [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A2).

Most of these are minor, cosmetic issues. But when it comes to the number zero, it's a problem. **The number zero looks like the letter 'o'**.

For example, I saw [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/299254/81764) and thought, "Why does this person want to store a letter in a raster cell? Rasters only store numbers, do they not understand how rasters work? ...Wait, *can* you store a letter in a raster?" > Down the rabbit hole searching for "storing letters in rasters." Did not get around to answering the question.

Answer (score 4):

This was raised by @AndreSilva in their [answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4950/115) to [GIS's updated site theme is live!](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4941)

@Catija (Stack Exchange staff member) commented there that:

> This isn't a display problem, it's [how Georgia renders
>   numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_(typeface)), actually.
>   Our default serif font is Georgia.

and:

> ... [here's an example on
>   Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/331614/what-is-3-force-and-3-acceleration).
>   Sites with sans serif fonts use Arial, which has all of the numbers on
>   the same baseline.

and:

> There's some generally broad concerns about Georgia from a few
>   different sites - [particularly in relation to
>   numbers](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/716/question-title-font-renders-0-number-zero-much-like-o-lower-case-letter).
>   We may have to reconsider it as our choice for serifed font... but my
>   understanding is that all sites with the same style of font (serif vs
>   sans) will have the same font stack.

For your feature request to progress I think that it would need to focus on having the GIS Stack Exchange site cease using Georgia font and begin using a font (like Arial) which has all of the numbers on the same baseline instead.

I do not know the history behind Georgia font being chosen for GIS SE and, personally, I would be happy for us to use Arial instead.

There seem to be a [number of Meta SE Q&As](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=georgia) about issues with the new responsive design and Georgia font but nothing that I could see related specifically to numbers.

An [answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1219) by @Shog9 (SE staff member) over at the Linux & Unix Meta may also be relevant.